# Mongoid : Eager loading count on has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm new with mongodb.

I'm trying to list some documents, my class has a `has_many` association, I would like to display the number of documents from this association.

Do I need to do some eager loading ?

If I use `includes` all the documents will be loaded, I only want the count.

Identity map is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a way to prevent eager loading from loading the full document.  I'd be curious to hear if that's possible now.

You can get the count like this:

```
ChildDoc.where(myclass_id: myclass_obj.id).count
```

So you're querying on the implicitly created foreign key field of the association.  This is still a query per parent doc, but the ideally fast query.

If perf is a real concern for you, you could write a single query that would return more data but in a single trip -- all the ids of the contained docs -- like this:

```
ChildDoc.where(myclass_id: {"$in" => list_of_myclass_objs.map {|x| x.id}}).only(:id, :myclass_id)
```

Since you're new to this, I'll add that you probably want to create the index on the FK field yourself -- mongoid doesn't do this for you.

```
class ChildDoc
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :myclass
    index({ myclass_id: 1 })
end
```

and then

```
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```